# Convert tuple contain string + int to string

Tags: python

I have this tuple for example: `("ABC", 5)` and I want to convert it into that `"ABC 5"`

I already tried to use `''.join(str(tuple))` but it doesn't work.

How can I do that?

Comment: `' '.join(map(str, t))` where `t` is your iterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the string formatting syntax. Otherwise see @erip's comment.

```
tuple = ("ABC", 5)
'{} {}'.format(*tuple)
# returns:
'ABC 5'
```

Comment: This is less extensible then `''.join(tupple)`. Can you rationalize why it's a better choice?

Comment: Using `''.join(tupple)` raises an exception because you have to convert the integer to a string first.  You could use `' '.join(map(str, tupple))`

Comment: There's a strictly more general version of this waiting to be borne. :-)

Comment: why does the * before the tupple is necessary?

Comment: @Daniel it is an iterable unpacking operator. most common use case that everybody encountered is func(*args). If you've never head of it, I highly suggest you to read about it, it is incredibly useful